# useState has its own memoazation?

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm encountering a warning related to React Hooks and state management that I would like to better understand. I have two code examples, and I'm curious about why one triggers a warning and the other does not.
Code example one

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Page = () => {
  let obj = { name: "sahand", age: true };
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
  }, [obj]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Code Example 2:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Page = () => {
  const [stateObj, setStateObj] = useState({ name: "sahand", age: true });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
  }, [stateObj]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

In the first example, using a variable obj to initialize the dependency array of useEffect triggers the following warning:
`
The 'obj' object makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 7) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'obj' in its own useMemo() Hook.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

`
However, in the second example, where I define the state using useState, there is no warning.

i know its about refrece type in js
My questions are:

Why does the first code example with let obj trigger a warning regarding the dependency array in useEffect? What is the significance of initializing obj outside of useState in this context?

Why does the second code example, where I use useState for state initialization, not trigger the warning? What's the difference in behavior here compared to the first example?

I would appreciate any insights or explanations about these differences in behavior and how React handles dependencies in the two scenarios. Thank you!
**as i understand , when you define reference-type variables (such as objects or arrays) inside useState, React is designed to maintain the reference to the same object across renders as long as you don't explicitly change it using the setState function provided by useState. This means React does not treat these variables as new references in every re-render.**

Comment: I think the bold section of the post pretty much answers it. What's inside useState is only evaluated at the first render and the reference is kept, this prevent rerenders in your second case

Answer (score 0):

As Axnyff mentioned, `useState` initializes the object only once when the component is mounted, so it can be used as a `useEffect` dependency. In the second example, the effect would execute only when `obj` changes through `setStateObj`. This is in contrast to the first case, where `obj` is initialized every time the component renders. Therefore, the useEffect in your second example is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Printed every render')
});
```

Notice that I didn't add `obj` as a dependency in this case because it's not needed. Since `obj` is created each re-render (which is non-optimal), you want to ensure that effects are called only when the state changes.

> useState has its own memoazation

So I think it's fair to say `useState` has its own memoization since it maintains the state between renders